# Ghostscript: split a multipage TIFF

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, tiff

Is it possible to use Ghostscript in order to split multipage TIFF?
I can't find anything in documentation but maybe it is possible because i can do it with PDF files.

The script i tried is:

```
gs -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=2 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiff24nc  -r600 -o output.tiff input.tiff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghostscript is a PDF and PostScript interpreter, it doesn't read TIFF files natively at all. I would imagine the command line you posted above threw PostScript errors, though you haven't mentioned that.

Because PostScript is a programming language it is, of course, possible to write a PostScript program to accomplish this task. However, this would be a long and tedious task even for an accomplished PostScript programmer as the language doesn't lend itself to this kind of activity.

It seems to me you'd be a lot better off using an image manipulation tool, possibly something like ImageMagick, to accomplish this.